# How to get [^\;]+ effect (performance) but with a sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to obtain the performant effect of `[^\;]+` but using an excluded sequence.
If you compare these two,

`[^\;]+`

`.*?\;`

string: `tatshdicndatsbba;`

the first one is faster(especially evident on bigger strings). That is the advantage. The former takes everything speedly except `;` while the latter is progressive, so slower.

If we have this
string: `tatshdi;cndatsbba;&djs`

that first regex doesnt work.
I would like to know how I could obtain the same performant effect with an excluded sequence instead of a single character (;)
Something like `[^(\;\&)]+` (I know it excludes `;` AND `&`, but lets say it is a new invented syntax for the sake of the explaination)

So when it meets a `;` it shoukd check if it is followed by `&`. If not, match it and continue. The trick is to obtain the same performant effect as the first regex I indicated

Edit:
Example

string: `tatshdi;cndatsbba;&djcaca;sduf;aa`

Expected match: `tatshdi;cndatsbba`, `&djcaca;sduf;aa`

Since the last two `;` are not followed by `&`, the match is not stopped and continues.

Comment: Hm... would you mind showing an example of a few source strings and the desired results? From your existing explanation, it is still unclear what you expect as an outcome of the "invented" regex.

Comment: Recommendation: Regex is _not_ what you want for performance. Write a program to extract what you  want. 10-50% performance boost right there.

Comment: What you want might be [`(?:(?!;&).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/2T28Ko/1)

Comment: I added an example string  and what matches I expect in the question

Comment: Why not use a `.split`? Example: `'tatshdi;cndatsbba;&djcaca;sduf;aa'.split(/;(?=&)/)` returns `["tatshdi;cndatsbba","&djcaca;sduf;aa"]` and its fast

Comment: @HaoWu it is too slow compared to ``.*?\;``

Comment: Anything _regex_ is slow (as of today). I have outperformed every regex 10-1000000x times when challanged. It's not a performace tool.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The field is regex. Outside? not interested.

Comment: @bobby324 What is the bigger real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This is close to the old https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Your question suggests that the priority is the fastest solution. Why does it have to be regexp? This seems more like a puzzle than a practical programming problem.

Comment: Again, the field of the problem is regex. I asked for an answer with regex. Not a puzzle. The question is is there a method or not?

Comment: In JavaScript regex, there is no way to only match any string of any length but a specific sequence of characters. You may create such a pattern only by matching what you do not need but matching and capturing what you need. Otherwise - and it is recommended - use workarounds, or - as everyone mentions here - code. I also understand the word "perform[ending]" is used here in the meaning of "work", the regex should yield the same result as when it is used with a single negated char.

Comment: You can "jump" from semi-colons to semi-colons using a repeated group like that: `[^;]+(?:;[^;&][^;]*)*` or something more flexible using a lookahead: `[^;]+(?:;(?!&)[^;]+)*`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you measure the performance, so let's use https://regex101.com (PCRE2 Flavor).

For the string `tatshdicndatsbba;`:

- the regex `[^\;]+` produces 1 matches in 3 steps
- the reges `.*?\;` produces 1 match in 19 steps

So, it's in accordance with your result.

Then, the for the string `tatshdi;cndatsbba;&djcaca;sduf;aa`

- the regex `[^\;]+` produces 5 matches in 14 steps (incorrect)
- the regex `.*?\;` produces 4 matches in 39 steps (incorrect)

The correct regex that produces exactly 2 matches is

- `&?(?:;?[^;&]+)+` - 2 matches in 29 steps

```js
let s = "tatshdi;cndatsbba;&djcaca;sduf;aa";
for (let m of s.matchAll(/&?(?:;?[^;&]+)+/g)) { console.log(m[0]); }
```

Another string with 3 matches:

```js
let s = "tatshdi;cndatsbba;&djcaca;sduf;aa;&djcaca;sd";
for (let m of s.matchAll(/&?(?:;?[^;&]+)+/g)) { console.log(m[0]); }
```